# Why is this message getting sent to the wrong client? (Deduping)

Tags: java, tcp, chat, server

I have a chat program. The problem is that I am trying to disallow dupe names. Essentially, whenever a name change request is sent to the server, it is checked against the list of names currently in use and if it is already taken, the person is added to my `shitlist` (not allowed to post) and they are sent a message that they need to change their name.

I commented the crap out of the code since there is a lot so you can understand it easily.

The problem is that the wrong person is being sent the message that the name is already in use! I have spent the last 8 hours trying to find it and It's bloody driving me mad!

The server side code is long; I'll post the relevant bits and any further will be provided on request. I'll also link to the complete program. (Not the source, the JAR.)

JAR: https://www.mediafire.com/?4t2shjdjf7blpg2

```
//...Irrelevant bits ommitted...//
public class Server
{
    // The server object reference
    static Server server;

    // Declarations:
    private ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> clientOutputStreams; // out streams
    private ArrayList<String> takenNames = new ArrayList<>(); // taken names
    private InetAddress ip;
    private final int serverPort; // the port the server is running on
    private static ObjectOutputStream changer; // the last person to change names
    private ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> shitList = new ArrayList<>();

    private HashMap <InetAddress, ObjectOutputStream> ipMap = 
            new HashMap<>(); // <ip, outputstream>

 //...Irrelevant bits ommited...//

// Don't mind this non-indentation, it is supposed to be.   
public void tellEveryone(Message message, InetAddress senderIP)
{
    // First check some special conditions..
    if(message.getType() == Message.TYPE.IN_USE)
    {
        try
        {
            changer.writeObject(message);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // If someone is on my shitlist,
    if(shitList.contains(ipMap.get(senderIP)))
    {
        // Warn them of their sins...
        Message nopeMessage = new Message(Message.TYPE.SERVER, 
            "You may not send any messages until you change your name!", 
                "Server");
        try
        {
            ipMap.get(senderIP).writeObject(nopeMessage);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Send message normally to everyone...
        // Sync, just to be safe
        synchronized(clientOutputStreams)
        {
            for(ObjectOutputStream oo : clientOutputStreams) // while more clients...
            {  
                try
                {
                    oo.writeObject(message);
                    oo.flush();
                }

                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("IOException caught during tellEveryone()");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(getTimeStamp() + ": Message Sent by:".
                concat(" " + senderIP + "/ " + message.getSenderName()));
    }
}
```

The server handler inner class...

```
    public class ServerHandler implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // Create a list of client out streams to send stuff...
            clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList<>();
            try // To establish a connection with clients
            {
                // Create server socket...
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
                while(true) // Will always run! Blocks!
                {
                    // Assign a client socket to any new socket connections...
                    // (The var used here is temp, but will be passed off soon.)
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    // Get's the ip of the client that connected...
                    ip = clientSocket.getInetAddress();
                    System.out.println(ip + " " + "connected.");
                    // Create ooStream to send messages to client...
                    ObjectOutputStream ooStream = 
                            new ObjectOutputStream(
                                    clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    // Add the client oo stream to the list of outputs...
                    clientOutputStreams.add(ooStream);
                    // Add user IP data to map of ip's
                    ipMap.putIfAbsent(ip, ooStream);
                    // Create new thread to run inner class ClientHandler...
                    Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
                    // Running the thread makes it safe to overwrite the... 
                    // ...clientsocket variable.
                    t.start();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception in server.run()");
                // TODO: Revise
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The client handler inner class

```
public class ClientHandler implements Runnable
{
    private ObjectInputStream oInStream; // The client's input stream.
    private Socket socket; // Socket to the client

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        try // to create an input stream...
        {
            socket = clientSocket; // <-- The one passed in to the method
            // Potential error from previous version... REMOVE WHEN TESTED
            oInStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error establishing input stream");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Message message;

        try // To process incoming messages...
        {
            while(socket.isClosed() == false) // If the socket is open...
            {
                // While there are more messages...
                // Also assigns to the message var.
                while((message = (Message)oInStream.readObject()) != null)
                {
                    // Passes on the message and sender info.
                    if(message.getType() == Message.TYPE.NAME_REQUEST)
                    {
                        changer = ipMap.get(socket.getInetAddress());
                        System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress());
                        System.out.println(changer.toString());
                        handleNameRequests(message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tellEveryone(message, ip); // TEST CHANGE- DELETED IF TEST
                    }
                }
                // TEST TEST TEST
                synchronized(clientOutputStreams)
                {
                    int index = 
                            clientOutputStreams.indexOf(
                                    socket.getOutputStream());
                    clientOutputStreams.remove(index);
                    System.out.println("Removed the client in sync");
                }
            }
            // TEST TEST TEST
            socket.close(); // TEST CLOSING SOCKET WHEN DONE.
            System.out.println("Sock closed after while loop in ch run()");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException caught when "
                    + "reading message.");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Some poor sap is going to have to debug"
                    + "this!");
        }
        finally
        {
            // THIS WHOLE BLOCK: TEST TEST TEST
            try
            {
                oInStream.close();
                System.out.println("just closed oinStream");
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Crap, added an old version of the source, fixing now!

Comment: Fixed! I think this is the correct code now. I was messing with it a lot to try and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I FINALLY FOUND IT!**

For any future people encountering a similar problem, the problem was that I was assigning the `ip` variable in the wrong place! This essentially resulted in the list of ip's being all the same! Another bug confounded that problem, in that when I disabled the sending ability of messages when on my `shitlist` (aren't programmers the darndest?), I disabled ALL types of messages, including those from the server, ect! Oops!

The lesson? Bugs hide in the darndest places. Walk through everything, and doubt what you know to be true. Assume nothing, verify everything. There are never enough print statements when debugging!